# React Hook useState empty array into set new array

Tags: reactjs

I was tried to assign useState method setUsers data array. i want assign get user data array into useState method initiail array

My code

```
   const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);
        
        useEffect(() => {
            axios.get('http://localhost:8000/api/users')
                .then(res => {
                    setUsers(u => [...u, res.data]);
                });
            console.log(users);
        },[]);
```

Comment: so whats your problem ? your console.log not update ?

Answer (score 1):

the **axios** get is run asynchronously, therefore the `console.log` statement will run before it successfully `setUsers`.

For better check, move the `console.log` inside `then()` :

```
    const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);
    
    useEffect(() => {
        axios.get('http://localhost:8000/api/users')
            .then(res => {
                setUsers(u => [...u, res.data]);
                console.log(users);
            });
        
    },[]);
```